# how do i create 2 tables with "filters" with crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have 2 columns in my ms excel database.

Column 1: Descriptors for a science subject
Column 2: A score, either "1" or "0". If the candidate got the descriptor correct, it shows "1". Otherwise it shows "2".

I need to Crystal Reports to generate a report showing 2 tables side-by-side. One table shows all the descriptors corresponding to what the candidate got correct (1). The other table shows that which the candidate got wrong (0).

how do I go about doing this?

I have limited programming knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: _I have limited programming knowledge_. Is that code for 'do it for me'?

Answer (score 0):

create two groups, first group on subject and the second group on score.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Didn't test the below code.

This statement is confusing.

```
Column 1: Descriptors for a science subject Column 2: A score, either "1" or "0". If the candidate got the descriptor correct, it shows "1". Otherwise it shows "2".
```

It should show '0' or '2'.

In any case create the report with steps below.

1. Group using `descriptors`  and now place 4 columns (Candidate name , score for correct and candidate name, score for wrong)in the detail section one for candidate got correct (1) and other for candidate got wrong (0)
2. create a formula and write `IF` condition where candidate score is 1 then candidate name for 1 column and `IF` candidae score is 0 then

Comment: Siva, I used the if then else statement. If score=1, descriptor corresponding to that score will show; same statement for that when score=2. What I have is 2 columns showing the right things but there are spaces between the row. For example, descriptorA and C has score=1; descriptorB has score=0. The column with the score=1 will show descriptorA, space, descriptorC, and this space corresponds to the same line on the other column showing descriptorC.How to i get rid of the space in between the rows?

Comment: Write a supress condition for column with score 1 write condition as `If score=1 then false else true ` and for score 0 write condition as `if score=0 then false else true` now space will be supressed

Comment: Siva i did the if then formula but the spaces between the rows are still there...

Comment: Only onr thing I can suggest is instead of space print something as `N/A`. I apologize if I am unable to answer your question.